# tcpclient reads fewer bytes than expected

Tags: c#, byte, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a problem with tcpclient, I need to send one or more files, so I have an application with server and client, the protocol is this :

1) I send some strings with information about number of files, files name and their sizes, all this with streamwriter.writeline (received from server with the function 
streamreader.readline)

2) After these strings I send the files, after each file the server answers to the client with a streamwriter.writeline of "ACK". The file is sent with the 
networkstream.write method, and received with networkstream.read.

The problem is that the server reads till the received bytes are equal to the file size, but... despite the client "seems" to send every byte of the file, the server 
receives fewer bytes in total! So the application is blocked in this step, the server is waiting for the next bytes and the client is waiting for the string of "ACK" 
with the streamreader.readline before to send the next file or just to finish the operation.

I also wanted to check what the server receives, so I print the number of bytes received during the reading cycle , discovering  that sometimes the server reads fewer bytes than the buffer size of the stream (fixed to 1024). This should be normal because TCP reads as soon as it can, it should not be the real problem, right? I can't 
believe that tcp loses bytes, but I don't know how to resolve.

Here you can find some part of codes :

----SERVER SIDE----------

```
..........Doing Stuffs.............
//secServer is the TCPListener socket.
this.secSHandler = secServer.AcceptTcpClient();
this.secSHandler.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024;
this.secSHandler.SendBufferSize = 1024;

this.is_connected_now = true;

print("is connected!!! ");

//Taking streams...
this.stream = this.secSHandler.GetStream();
this.sr = new StreamReader(stream);
this.sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

string first = sr.ReadLine();
print("I read + " + first + " .");
int numFiles = 0;
string connType = first.Substring(0, 6);
    if (connType.CompareTo("CLIENT") == 0)
    {
    //SINCR CLIENT -> SERVER
    string clipType = first.Substring(7, 4);
        if (clipType.CompareTo("FILE") == 0)
        {
        //CASE RECEIVE FILE

        int posSeparator = first.IndexOf('*');
        string nFiles = first.Substring(12, first.Length - 13);
        numFiles = Convert.ToInt16(nFiles);
        string[] fileNames = new string[numFiles];
        int[] fileSizes = new int[numFiles];

            //TAKE FROM THE CLIENT ALL FILE NAMES AND SIZES
            for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
            {
            fileNames[i] = sr.ReadLine();
            print("Name file : I read " + fileNames[i]);
            string dim = sr.ReadLine();
            fileSizes[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dim);
            print("Size file : I read " + fileSizes[i]);
            }

            //RECEVING FILES
            for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
            {
            receive_single_file_1(stream, fileSizes[i], fileNames[i]); //CANNOT GO AFTER THIS POINT
            sw.WriteLine("File sent - number " + i);    
            sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }   
.............Doing others stuffs.............

sr.Close();
sw.Close();
```

THE FUNCTION RECEIVE SINGLE FILE IS HERE BELOW

```
public bool receive_single_file_1(NetworkStream netstream, int size, string filename)
{

    int sizeToRead = 0;


    string f_name = "";
    //...f_name is the result of another operation, for the sake of the example i write only the final instruction
    f_name = filename;

    byte[] RecData = new byte[1024];
    int RecBytes = 0;

    try
    {

        int totalrecbytes = 0;
        FileStream Fs = new FileStream((tempFold + f_name), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        //COUNTER OF THE WHILE
        int nciclo = 0;
        while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read(RecData, 0, 1024)) > 0)
        {
        //I defined print in another context...
        totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
        if(RecBytes!=1024)
        print("Cycle : "+ nciclo +" Content RecBytes : " + RecBytes + " e RecData.Length : " + RecData.Length + " byte reads : " + totalrecbytes + ".");

        Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);

        if (totalrecbytes >= size)
        {
            print("Read all bytes " + totalrecbytes + " over " + size + " .");
            break;
        }

        //Refresh the buffer
        RecData = new byte[1024];

        nciclo++;
        }

print("End of transfer. Received " + totalrecbytes + "File :" + filename + " Saved on " + tempFold);
Fs.Close();


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Ok here i return false, but i do some other stuff before
return false;
}

return true;
}
```

----END OF SERVER SIDE--------------

--------CLIENT SIDE--------------

```
.....DOING STUFFS....
//sw is the streamWriter, Sr the streamReader and the stream is the networkstream

System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection formats = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
sw.WriteLine("CLIENT:FILE:" + formats.Count + "*");
sw.Flush();
   //Sending to the server filename and relative size
   foreach (string filename in formats)
    {
      //Ok the * has sense in my protocol...ignore it.
      sw.WriteLine((Directory.Exists(filename)) ? System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename) + "*" : System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename));
      sw.Flush();
      FileStream Fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      sw.WriteLine(Fs.Length);
      sw.Flush();
      stream.Flush();
      Fs.Close();
     }
     //Sending files     
     foreach (string filename in formats)
     {    
    //client_sync is the class that wrap the TcpClient socket
        client_sync.send_single_file(stream, filename);
        resp = sr.ReadLine();                
     }
....DOING STUFF AND end of this function...

The send file function is defined in this way :
(note : i take this function from code project some weeks ago)
public void send_single_file(NetworkStream netstream, string filename)
        {
        //connected is a param of my class
            if (!connected) return;
            byte[] SendingBuffer = null;
            try
            {

                FileStream Fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                int NoOfPackets = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(Fs.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(this.BufferSize)));
        //NOTE: BUFFERSIZE IS 1024
                int TotalLength = (int)Fs.Length, CurrentPacketLength = 0;
                int bytes_send = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < NoOfPackets; i++)
                {
                    if (TotalLength > this.BufferSize)
                    {
                        CurrentPacketLength = this.BufferSize;
                        TotalLength = TotalLength - CurrentPacketLength;
                    }
                    else
                        CurrentPacketLength = TotalLength;

                    SendingBuffer = new byte[CurrentPacketLength];
                    Fs.Read(SendingBuffer, 0, CurrentPacketLength);
                    netstream.Write(SendingBuffer, 0, SendingBuffer.Length);
                    bytes_send += CurrentPacketLength;

                }
                Fs.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                netstream.Close();
                //my function
                close_connection();
            }
            netstream.Flush();

        }
```

---------END OF CLIENT SIDE------

So...someone can help me to escape from this hell??? THX :)

Comment: Short version: you probably should not be mixing TextReader/Writer with Streams. The StreamReader class buffers data, and may be grabbing some of the bytes intended for the binary portion of the transmission. Either handle the text decoding yourself, so you have control over the buffering, or use a control-channel design like FTP (where you have one connection to exchange commands as text, and another channel to exchange binary data).

Comment: Ok thanks! I tried to eliminate every instance of StreamWriter or StreamReader, using only NetworkStream to communicate.And it works!